# Airflow: GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

Trying to load data into bigquery from google cloud storage via airflow GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator operator.

Getting below error. need suggestion regarding the below error.

Code:

```
load_into_bq = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id=get_task_id("load_into_bq", flow_name),
            bucket='bigquery-source-replication',
            source_objects=flow_details["gcs_csv_filename"],
            destination_project_dataset_table='project-141508.dwh_test.datalake_production_products_intermediate',
            source_format="CSV",
            create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
            autodetect=True,
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id=GCP_CONN_ID,
            bigquery_conn_id=BQ_CONN_ID,
            dag=dag
        )
```

LOGS:

```
[2021-06-10 09:56:54,522] {taskinstance.py:902} INFO - Executing <Task(GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator): flow_name_load_into_bq> on 2021-06-10T09:55:01.281248+00:00
[2021-06-10 09:56:54,599] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 13009 to run task
[2021-06-10 09:56:54,854] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'mysql_to_gcs_data_dag', 'flow_name_load_into_bq', '2021-06-10T09:55:01.281248+00:00', '--job_id', '19338', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/mysql_gcs_bq_poc_sourav.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpypa_dgaw']
[2021-06-10 09:56:54,860] {standard_task_runner.py:78} INFO - Job 19338: Subtask flow_name_load_into_bq
[2021-06-10 09:56:56,025] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: mysql_to_gcs_data_dag.flow_name_load_into_bq 2021-06-10T09:55:01.281248+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-567675b8f5-t58ns
[2021-06-10 09:56:56,834] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:145} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
```

Comment: It seems that your `bigquery_conn_id` and `google_cloud_storage_conn_id` uses custom connections. Did you assign them the correct key file, scope, project id, etc as shown in https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_a_connection_to_another_project?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be with GCP connection and not with the operator itself.

There are 3 ways to authenticate with GCP:

1. Use Application [Default Credentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default)
2. Use a [service account key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#service_accounts) file (JSON format) on disk - Keyfile Path.
3. Use a service account key file (JSON format) from connection configuration - Keyfile JSON.

You are getting this error since you didn't set any of the options.

First `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` is deprecated. You should import `GCSToBigQueryOperator` as:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
```

For Airflow >= 2.0.0:
Install [Google provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-google
```

Once installed you can follow the instructions on the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html#configuring-the-connection) and setup the connection in any of the options listed above.

For Airflow < 2.0.0:
Install [Google backport provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

Once installed you can follow the instructions on the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/howto/connection/gcp.html#configuring-the-connection) and setup the connection in any of the options listed above.